# Sticky header on top in canvas app - powerapps

Tags: canvas, dynamic, scroll, header, powerapps

I have header section in my app . In there i have many details like model name, model description, accuracy value , image and back button

after scrolled to a particular position in canvas app i want the header to show only the model name and back button (something like reducing the header  height to half of its original one)

Do we have anything in canvas app to behave similarly like this

In this example [here](https://bootstrapshuffle.com/classes/navbar/navbar+sticky-top)

here is an header part

[full header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OpRNS.png)

when i scroll to some position only the below things will appear in UI as header

[after scrolled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1lSv.png)

do we have anything similar to this in canvas app or any workaround to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

Depending on whether the important part of your header is at the top of your header or at its bottom:

1. At the top: make 2 containers. Only the sticky header elements should go into the first one, set this container to be on top. The rest of the header elements should go into the second, vertical container, on top, so they would disappear first when scrolling.
2. At the bottom: Add a vertical container with 2 child vertical containers. All header elements should go into the first one, with the sticky ones as last. Make a note of the sticky part's height, or group them. The second child container should host all scrollable elements. This one should have a height like (Screen height) - (sticky group's height) - (sticky footer's height, if any). This would result in the upper part of the header scroll out of sight but the sticky part always showing. Downside: double scrollbar.

   Alternatively, you could set have a header container/group with conditional Y bound to a boolean variable. Any interaction with the non-header group could then trigger a negative shift of the header group leaving only the important part visible. You can also bind this to a manual collapse/x button.

Comment: I think the 1st option applies to me..i followed what you have shared.. but i couldnt achieved